# Changing Peppers voice

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I am working on a story, that Pepper tells. This story has 4 characters - 2 men and 2 women. Is it possible to make Pepper sound like a men / women while speaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the pitch of peppers voice to sound more male/female.
To change the pitch in choregraphe you adjust the Voice shaping parameter.

[image: Settings for the Say box]

If you are coding in python then the syntax is:

```
tts.say("\\vct=150\\My name is Juliet")
tts.say("\\vct=50\\Now I am Romeo")
```

Some more details on the voice shaping [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-tuto.html?highlight=pitch).
The same syntax can be used in Dialog scripts.

Comment: How could I set this global in the Dialog scripts (file extension `dlg`)?

Comment: Not possible I'm afraid. You have to write it for each single line of dialog.